# Async version of ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<TElement> Method (String, ObjectParameter[]) in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I cannot find async version of ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction in entity framework 6.0. Is it planned in the next version? Is there a simple way to implement it, so I can use it now?